# Copy reference instead of new deep copy

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping for copying a Person and a State, but when I copy state, I don't want deep copy of a person, only reference, but I am using automapper to create a deep copy of person somewhere else too, so there is a mapping for person and for state.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class State
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CopyByReference()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<State, State>();

        var original = new State { Name = "Start", CreatedBy = new Person { Name = "Employee name" } };
        var copy = Mapper.Map<State>(original);
        Assert.AreEqual(original.Name, copy.Name);
        if (!ReferenceEquals(original.CreatedBy, copy.CreatedBy))
        {
            throw new Exception("I need a reference copy, not deep copy.");
        }
    }
```

I have tried to implement an IValueResolver, but I got deep copy too. I could simply ignore the CreatedBy property and copy reference after mapping, but that is pretty ugly and looks very prone to an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automapper is not really designed for this, so it will always try to use a mapping if it finds one, so it always tries to map your `Person` objects...

One workaround would be to `Ignore` the `CreatedBy` on your `State` and copy over it in the `AfterMap` callback:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<State, State>()
    .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, c => c.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => { dest.CreatedBy = src.CreatedBy; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove this line: `Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>();`

That should make AutoMapper copy the reference and not perform a deep copy.